# Confused between $\frac{\left(13\:nCr\:1\right)\cdot \:\:\left(12\:nCr\:1\right)}{52\:nCr\:2}$ or $\frac{\left(13\:nCr\:2\right)}{52\:nCr\:2}$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Say we're trying to find the probability of choosing 2 hearts out of a 52 deck of cards, then I get confused between writing  $\frac{\left(13\:nCr\:1\right)\cdot \:\:\left(12\:nCr\:1\right)}{52\:nCr\:2}$ or writing $\frac{\left(13\:nCr\:2\right)}{52\:nCr\:2}$. The first one makes intuitive sense because once you pick one card, there are only 12 more hearts left, but the latter seems to be the right answer

Comment: favorable outcomes = $13 * 12$   possible outcomes = $52 * 51$. the notation of your formula is unclear, what is $nCr$?

Comment: In your first answer, the denominator only includes all sets of two cards, not all ordered pairs, but in the numerator each allowed ordered pair is included, so you count each allowed set of two twice. In your second answer, you count sets of two in both numerator and denominator, which is correct. In the comment from https://math.stackexchange.com/users/701966/l4telearner they count each ordered pair in both numerator and denominator, so that is also correct.

Comment: $nCr = \dfrac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first answer is wrong because you considered ordered selections in the numerator and unordered selections in the denominator.  This problem can be solved by using either ordered selections or unordered selections, but you must make consistent choices in the numerator and the denominator to obtain the correct answer.

**Ordered selections:**  There are $52$ possible choices for the first card, which leaves $51$ possible choices for the second card.

For the favorable cases, there are $13$ ways to select a heart with the first selection.  Given that a heart has been selected on the first draw, there are $12$ ways to select a heart on the second draw.

Hence, the probability of selecting two hearts when two cards are selected at random from a standard deck is
$$\Pr(\text{two hearts}) = \frac{13}{52} \cdot \frac{12}{51} = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{4}{17} = \frac{1}{17}$$

**Unordered selections:**  There are
$$\binom{52}{2}$$
ways to select a subset of two of the $52$ cards in a standard deck.

For the favorable cases, there are
$$\binom{13}{2}$$
ways to select a subset of two of the $13$ hearts in a standard deck.

Hence, the probability of selecting two hearts when two cards are selected at random from a standard deck is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{two hearts}) & = \frac{\dbinom{13}{2}}{\dbinom{52}{2}}\\
                       & = \frac{\dfrac{13!}{2!11!}}{\dfrac{52!}{2!50!}}\\[2 mm]
                       & = \frac{\dfrac{13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11!}{2!\cdot 11!}}{\dfrac{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50!}{2!50!}}\\[2 mm]
                       & = \frac{\dfrac{13 \cdot 12}{2!}}{\dfrac{52 \cdot 51}{2!}}\\[2 mm]
                       & = \frac{13 \cdot 12}{2!} \cdot \frac{2!}{52 \cdot 51}\\[2 mm]
                       & = \frac{13 \cdot 12}{52 \cdot 51}\\[2 mm]
                       & = \frac{1}{17}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying the same thing as the comments is that when you are expressing a probability by enumerating the numerator and denominator, you must be consistent in deciding whether order of selection matters.

That is, if you express the probability as

$$\frac{N}{D},$$

and compute $N$ and $D$ combinatorically, you must do one of the following:

- Either decide that order of selection will be deemed irrelevant when computing each of $N,D$. 
  Under such a decision, the computation would be 
  $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{13}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}.$
- Or decide that order of selection will be deemed relevant, when computing each of $N,D$. 
  Under such a decision, the computation would be 
  $\displaystyle \frac{(2!) \times \binom{13}{2}}{(2!) \times\binom{52}{2}}.$

Notice that as a general rule, if you are selecting $n$ items, $k$ at a time then:

- If order of selection is regarded as irrelevant, then the computation is 
  $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}.$
- If order of selection is regarded as relevant, then the computation is 
  $\displaystyle (k!) \times \binom{n}{k}.$

In the second bullet point above, the $(k!)$ factor accommodates that there are $(k!)$ ways of ordering the items to be selected.  So, when order is regarded as important, you are in effect, performing a **two-step** process.

First, you are selecting the $(k)$ items, without any regard as to how they are ordered.  Then, you are ordering them.